# JS openID selector for DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo, openid, spring-security

I've found openid selector http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/ which supports with jQuery, MooTools and prototype.

Is there anything similar, compatible with DOJO or can I make it work with DOJO somehow?

I'm planning to use it with Spring Security.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [alternatives](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries)? You can try [Zend OpenID](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html) library. Since Zend uses Dojo's Ajax, that might be your best bet. Or maybe you can use the java based ones.

Comment: Thanks, will try and let you now

Answer (score 0):

You can not as it is make it work but with some modifications it can work for dojo too.
I have created a modification for dojo or u can say a dojo widget version of that .Check once it should work although i have not tested.let me know if you face any issues.Compare with jquery version to see the things properly and understand it

Download from here
http://iput.it/e7db6b

Comment: Make Sure to place the file in proper location as the name of the widget is "openId.provider.Selector"   so place the file in your root dojo package in folder structure openId/provider/Selector.js                       Rename the file to Selector.js before using  and then just like any other component  you can use it like dojo.require("openId.provider.Selector")